# use two UIPickerView in the same class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I wrote this code for the first UIPickerView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                      @"http://localhost:8080/Data/resources/converter.country/"];
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request startAsynchronous];
      //  countrys = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
        countrys.delegate = self;
        countrys.dataSource = self;
        countrys.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        countryField.inputView=countrys;


     - (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        NSString *codeCity;
        codeCity=[countriesArray objectAtIndex:row];
        return codeCity;
    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        return [countriesCodeArray count];
    }
```

And then i wanted to make another UIPickerView with cities . I wrote this

```
 citys.delegate = self;
    citys.dataSource = self;
    citys.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    cityField.inputView=citys;
```

But when i click on it i have countries list . How should i change the datasource ? And how to use the default function of the UIPickerView, like numberOfComponentsInPickerView , numberOfRowsInComponent: ... with the second UIPickerView ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can assign tag to your pickerviews and then can check these tags in datasource/delegate methods

```
citysPickerview.tag = 2

otherPickerview.tag = 1


// then you can check for these tags in pickerview datasource/delegate methods like this - 

- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

        NSString *title;

      if (pickerview.tag == 1) // this is otherPickerview
      {
          title=[countriesArray objectAtIndex:row]; // your logic to get title for otherpickerview


      }
      else if (pickerview.tag == 2) // this is citysPickerview
      {
         title=[countriesArray objectAtIndex:row]; // your logic to get title for cityspickerview


      }

  return title;

}
```

You should follow this same mechanism in your all datasource/delegate code :)

Comment: You could also use "if (pickerView == cityPickerView)..."

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is set `tag` for the 2 `UIPickerView`, like so - `[countryPicker setTag:1]`, use these tags to distinguish between the 2 picker views.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
        return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if([pickerView tag] == 1)
        return [countryNames count];
    else
        return [cityNames count];

}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if([pickerView tag] == 1)
        return [countryNames objectAtIndex:row];
    else 
        return [cityNames count];

}
```

Comment: well, thats the only way to use 2 or more uipickerviews using the same datasource !

Comment: yes...but you should read other answers before posting yours.. and don't post similar answers instead upvote existing answers!

Comment: thank you. It does not matter, especially since the second response is more complete

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler solution, just compare the pickerView pointer.  That way you save the additional complexity and maintenance of using tags.

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSInteger numberOfRows = 0;

    if (pickerView == countrys) {
        numberOfRows = [countriesCodeArray count];
    }
    else if (pickerView == citys) {
        numberOfRows = [citysCodeArray count];
    }

    return numberOfRows;
}
```

Note: This answer is based on giuseppe's comment.