# Spinning 2 UIPickerView simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

For some esthetic reasons, I want to implement two `UIPickerView` instead of having only one with two custom view inside (the wider the `UIPickerView` is, the more we can see a curve on the extremities, and I don't want to see it).

So, I would like to know if it is possible to spin the two picker views simultaneously so that it give the impression there are only one.

Comment: Have you tried with tag?. For example., [http://stackoverflow.com/a/8436051/2629258](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8436051/2629258)

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. What I'm looking for is when you move (with your finger) one of the picker views, the other one follow exactly at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a solution but in the end, it doesn't resolve that much my esthetic problem... Anyway here is a way I found but it's quite CPU demanding.

Each `UIPickerView` has a `UIScrollView` in it. First you find it, once you found it, you set the delegate to your picker view class:

```
private func findScrollView(view: UIView) -> UIScrollView? {
    if view is UIScrollView {
        return view as? UIScrollView
    }
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if let scrollView = findScrollView(subview as UIView) {
            scrollView.delegate = self
            return scrollView
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then in your `UIPickerView` class, implement this:

```
extension MyPickerView: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        switch scrollView {
            case pickerView1:
                pickerView2.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: pickerView2.contentOffset.x, y: pickerView1.contentOffset.y)
            case pickerView2:
                pickerView1.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: pickerView1.contentOffset.x, y: pickerView2.contentOffset.y)
            default: break
        }
    }
}
```